# Toggle hidden state of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the press of a button to toggle the hidden state of a couple of UILabels. Press the button once, it unhides them, press again the labels are hidden, the default state for these labels being hidden.

Here is what I thought would work (but obviously does not):

```
@IBAction func information(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    if(infoLocation.hidden = true)
    {
        self.infoLocation.hidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        self.infoLocation.hidden = true
    }

    //**********************************//
    if(infoName.hidden = true)
    {
        self.infoName.hidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        self.infoName.hidden = true
    }

    //**********************************//
    if(infoVersion.hidden = true)
    {
        self.infoVersion.hidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        self.infoVersion.hidden = true
    }


}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the code called? Are the labels ever visible? Be specific

Comment: The code does not works... The labels should hide/show but does not

Comment: infoLocation.hidden = !infoLocation.hidden this toggles the labels status, in your if, you assigned the BOOL instead of checking with ==

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make the code shorter (and look better) I would do like this if its just a  toggle:

```
for label in [label1, label2, label3, label4] {
    label.hidden = !label.hidden
}
```

This will toggle label1-4.hidden

Answer (score 6):

Use `==` inside of your `if` statement, not `=`.

```
if(infoVersion.hidden == true)
```

`=` is for assignment.
`==` is for equality.

**update** : 
You can use a faster version code to toogle hidden status :

```
infoVersion.hidden = !infoVersion.hidden;
```

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 3.x, 4.x**

```
for label in [label1, label2, label3, label4] {
    label.isHidden = !label.isHidden
}
```

Comment: So actually not any different from the accepted answer from over a year ago :D

Comment: yes, not really, I just wanted to clarify that we use **isHidden** in Swift 3 instead of **hidden**

Comment: just to correct by syntax as per Swift 3.x


self.label.isHidden = !label.isHidden

Comment: @chaitanya **self** does not needs to be explicit in every context.This update is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.x**

```
label.isHidden = true // or false
```